# Is there is way to preserve the state in astro

Tags: routes, svelte, astrojs

I would really like to know if there is a way of preserving states such as user data between routes in astro. I am also using the svelte framework.

I tried to use svelte stores but does not seem to work. I also tried to implement nano stores but that does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Astro currently [suggests using nano stores](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/sharing-state), but in order to make nano stores persist across all pages you must use [`@nanostores/persistent`](https://github.com/nanostores/persistent)